# Validating HTTP response in swagger

Tags: rest, api, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

Is it possible to validate an HTTP response in swagger editor and/or swagger ui? I need to check that a particular response has exactly the structure and data i want.
For example the body has to be {"message":"pong"}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger Editor and Swagger UI do not validate API responses against the schema. The corresponding [feature request](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2087) was marked as "nice to have" but "out of scope for the project for now".

However, since these projects are open source, you could implement this feature yourself and submit a pull request.